# Write quantities to specific journal - Odoo v8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

What I need is to automatically write some quantities to a specific journal, read'em and write them on debit or credit fields, depending on the situation.

But, the whole point is, that I need to do this:

1.- Without creating invoices

2.- Depending on the state of class/table

3.- Without adding the function to any field, so as soon as it changes state, the quantites are written into the journal.

Ive tried this method, but I think this doesn't works because it should be on a `computed` Float or Integer field:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('order_picking', 'order_picking.isbn', 'contract_worksheet')
def accounting_scenarios(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.state == awaitingraw:
            record.isbn.printer_wip_account.debit = record.contract_worksheet.total_alles
        elif record.state == work_in_progress:
            record.transporter.transp_transit.debit = record.contract_worksheet.total_alles
```

So, it basically does nothing.

I need a behaviour like, when a purchase or sale is done, the `debit` or `credit` fieds are updated with the invoices generated. BUT in this case, the invoice isn't necessary, I just need to read, and copy some field (computed or not), and then "paste" this on the aforementioned fields of the selected journal.

I hope I've explained myself.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which type of fields are `isbn`, `printer_wip_account`, `transporter`, `transp_transit`, `contract_worksheet` and `total_alles`?

Comment: isbn = Many2one to produdct.product, printer_wip_account is a res.partner journal account, transporter is a res.partner, transp_transit, the transporter's account journnal, contract_worksheet is a One2many to another model (from which the calculations are going to be read), total_alles is one of those computed fields which belongs to contract_worksheet model

Comment: Idk if I should change the way on which I'm attacking this problem though

Comment: What should be done is read fields from One2many contract_worksheet, write the result into debit or credit fields, on a specific journal, depending on a state, but I'm complicating things maybe...

Comment: I think that a related field on a One2many cannot be called like a Many2one related one, ie: many2one.related, I think it should be one2many.many2onefromotherclass.related , maybe that's one of the issues

Comment: Ok, I managed to use this concept for the same record, now I need to copy it to the selected journal, I'll think on how to do that or open a new question for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to perform some action each time a field changes, but you don't need to create a new field which calls a compute method (which uses `@api.depends` decorator), you should overwrite the ORM `write` method of the model the field belongs to. So, in your case I would do something like this:

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    res = super(YourModel, self).write(vals)
    if 'state' in vals:
        for record in self:
            contract_worksheet = record.contract_worksheet
            if record.state == awaitingraw:
                printer_wip_account = record.isbn.printer_wip_account
                res &= printer_wip_account.write({
                    'debit': sum(c.total_alles for c in contract_worksheet),
                })
            elif record.state == work_in_progress:
                transp_transit = record.transporter.transp_transit
                res &= transp_transit.write({
                    'debit': sum(c.total_alles for c in contract_worksheet),
                })
    return res
```

The above code may not be accurate, because I don't know the type of all the fields you're using there, but, you can't take the value of `One2many` field directly, you need to loop it to get the values you want. I'm supposing the field `total_alles` is a computed `Float`, and each `contract_worksheet` record has a different value for it, so you have to sum them to get a only float to write in `debit` value.

Comment: I think this is really good start, Thank You, although I think I've found something else, anyways, I'll open a new question for that matter, Thank You very much